# Dynamically add new field with same key name in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Im trying to create a list on one of my collections in a dynamic way, here is an example.

```
var user = mongoose.Schema({
"NAME": String,
"LAST": String,
"EMAIL": String,
"TasksUploaded": {}
```

})

And what I want to do in mongoose is update the user with the tasks he has already uploaded, what is the best way to do this? what i want at the end is this:

```
{
    "Name" : "John",
    "Last" : "Doh",
    "Email" : "john@doh.com",
    "TasksUploaded" : {
        "Task" : "Task A"
        "Task" : "Task B"
        "Task" : "Task H"
        "Task" : "Task F"
        "Task" : "Task C"
    }
}
```

As you can see the task are not always consecutive and the user can upload them as he wants.

Im new to all this new NoSQL and MongoDB stuff, so if you could tell what is the best practice i would appreciate it.

This is how I currently update it but what happens is that the "Level" gets replaced and y need to add a new line to the docuemnt.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id}, { $set: { 'TasksUploaded.Task': req.body.task} }, { returnNewDocument: true, new: true }, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error saving task: " + err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(result);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Single backticks are for _inline_ code. Don't use them for multiline codeblocks. Either use an indentation of 4 spaces or triple backticks (AKA code fencing)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that's not possible. You can't have several keys with the same name in an object. Just imagine, how would you address them?

It seems that you need to restructure your data and use arrays.

Comment: How would you recommend on doing this? what i have also though is doing it this way `{
    "Name" : "John",
    "Last" : "Doh",
    "Email" : "john@doh.com",
    "TasksUploaded" : {
        "Task A" : true
        "Task B" : true
        "Task H" : true
        "Task F" : true
        "Task C" : true
    }
}`

Comment: @mandaman2k It can be as TasksUploaded ["TaskA","TaskB","TaskC"]

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Sam,

I modified my structure to add the upload tasks in a form of an array

`TasksUploaded ["TaskA","TaskB","TaskC"]`

Thank you